# How can I return the last array inside this recursive method?

Tags: recursion, arraylist, methods, collections, return

I'm coding a calculator that simplifies a string of operations to arraylists of positive and negative results.
Right now, im trying to deal with adding the parenthesees feature and I thought about creating arraylists inside others to represent the operations within them.
There is only 1 method that processes everything, so when I add "(" an arraylist must be created in the current position of the array, and signify in some way to the rest of the code that next time the method goes in, it must start in that inner array.
So i thought about doing a recursive method that returns the "deepest" arraylist that has no more arrays inside.

```
 public ArrayList<Object> deepest(ArrayList<Object> al){
            ArrayList<Object> input=new ArrayList<>(al);
            for(Object o:input){
                if(o instanceof ArrayList){
                   return deepest((ArrayList<Object>) o);
                }
            }
           return input;
}
```

Is this actually returning the deepest array inside the "tree" ? My code is doing some unexpected stuff and I feel like this starts to escape my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach would return a leftmost `ArrayList`, not the deepest (the very first it finds in the tree). For the deepest, you would need a more exhaustive search, a counter that keeps track of the current depth, and also calculation of the "deepest so far" item at the appropriate places (after visiting all elements of an `ArrayList`).